# Opencart stock status display

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am looking for a way to display Out of stock status on product page(OC 2.1.0.1). I have set multiple stock statuses for different product groups but out of stock status only appears when qty is 0. I would like it to display no matter the qty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this by making a boolean method isOutOfStock() which checks if the quantity is 0, and if true, display (This Item is Out of Stock) and if false display (This item is currently in stock!).